# What causes "unresolvable conflict(s)" when renaming in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, rename

I get an error that there are "unresolvable conflict(s)" when renaming certain identifiers in Visual Studio. What's causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The file was a temporary file opened from source control, not part of the solution. I assume Visual Studio was unable to determine all instances of the identifier from just the isolated file. Renaming the method in the actual project file succeeded with no issues.

Comment: I had the same problem when i copied a new version of a code file (with new file name but the same class name) into solution, without deleting the older one, which caused a conflict between two classes with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, another way this can happen is if...
step 1) You start writing a method call that doesn't match the signature of the original method, i.e. the arguments don't line-up and you're getting warnings.
step 2) Try to rename the original method.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen in Visual Studio 2017, but one case in particular that is confusing is when I check "Include comments" and there are  tags referencing the symbol in XML comments.

If you uncheck that setting the XML references are updated correctly, and there are no warnings of a conflict, so it seems that the "conflict" in this case is Visual Studio trying to rename those occurrences twice – once as a normal symbol rename and once as a find/replace in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if the new name is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when the identifier you are trying to change is used in a line that has a compile time error. So; search for that line with error, fix or comment out it, and then try again. This worked for me.